# Single import insert python

Tags: python, import, formatting, isort

Hi I'm trying to insert one import across many files. I tried isort but it does more than insert the one import. It adds additional imports and groups others. I don't want that  many changes in my MR. I'm trying to follow continuous delivery of making one small distinct change at a time.

Does anybody have experience just appending an import to the last import in python files?

Thanks!

Comment: Unless you have hundreds of files, it really should be faster and safer to do this by hand.

Comment: Yeah it's a lot of files. Its a big monolith:(

Comment: I found solution with awk. I'll post it when I finalized and test it.